# La página se carga sin oprimir el botón de búsqueda

Tags: php, mysql

Cuando oprimo el botón para abrir la página, me sale el error:
`Notice: Undefined index: cgcpf_dev in ...\form.php on line 54`

Ocurre que cuando lleno la caja y oprimo el botón de búsqueda ya no me sale error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solo ocurre cuando cargo la página por primera vez.

```html
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label style="margin-left:-45px; " class="col-sm-2"><b>CPF_CNPJ<b></label>
       <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input  style="margin-left:-140px;width: 140px;" type="text" class="form-control"  name="cgcpf_dev" autocomplete="off" required>
       </div>
   </div>
</form
```

```
<?php
   $cgcpf_dev = $_POST['cgcpf_dev'];
   $idemp = $_POST['id_credor']; 
?>

if(isset($cgcpf_dev)&& !empty($idemp)){

            $params = array($cgcpf_dev,$idemp);       
            $options =  array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );       
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);       
            $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

            if ($stmt == false) {
                die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

             while($row  =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            
            ......
}
```

Comment: Uhm veo que dejaste el código de `if(isset)...`fuera de las etiquetas de php... o simplemente fue un error al introducir el código dentro de tu pregunta...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todo tu código lo tienes en un mismo archivo, estas intentando acceder a parámetros que aun no se han recibido.

```
$cgcpf_dev = $_POST['cgcpf_dev'];
$idemp = $_POST['id_credor'];
```

Puedes corregir este inconveniente haciendo una comprobación para saber si existe algún valor antes de intentar obtenerlos.

```
$cgcpf_dev = isset($_POST['cgcpf_dev']) ? $_POST['cgcpf_dev']:"";
$idemp = isset($_POST['id_credor']) ? $_POST['id_credor']: "";
```

Saludos.

Comment: Carlos gracias por el aporte. He cambiado ele codigo e resultou correto.